# Dynamic return types through java generics

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I need something like dynamic return type from my function. My code at this moment is like:

```
@Repository
public class SswltDataDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SswltDataDAO.class);
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource_sswlt")
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public List<Object> getSswltData(String tableName, String sql, Class className) {
        List<Object> listOfOblects = null;
        try{
            listOfOblects  = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(className));
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("\n\nException while importing data from "+tableName+":\n", e);
            listOfOblects = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return listOfOblects;
    }

}
```

And this is the usage of method: dataImportFromSswltToIwproImp()

```
Class MainService {
    public boolean dataImportFromSswltToIwproImp() {
        .......

        List<Object> list = sswltDataDAO.getSswltData("tbl_sswltdata_addresses", "select * from tbl_sswltdata_addresses", SswltdataAddresses.class);

        .........;
    }
}
```

Using Generics I want to write method getSswltData() in such a way that rather then returning `List<Object>` it should dynamically return `List<class name>` i.e. list of class type objects, not of Object class objects. Please note "Class Name" is the Class which is passed during the calling of getSswltData() and this will be the dynamic part of the code.

I am curious that it is still possible or not? I am flexible enough to change any part of my code so all suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the signature that's possible:

```
<T> List<T> getSswltData(String tableName, String sql, Class<T> className)
```

That way you define the return value to be a list of instance of the class you passed as a parameter.

Internally you might have to do some casts/conversions though, since I'd guess that `jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(className));` just returns a `List<Object>`. If you are *very sure* that you actually get a `List<T>` you could try to cast to the raw type `List` and from that to `List<T>` but you'll need to be aware that you might introduce hard to spot bugs if the returned element don't match the passed class.

Comment: Thanks. just wondering how to cast within this line itself : listOfObjects  = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(className)); what changes I need to place in this line?

Comment: Basically `listOfObjects = (List)...` - but please read the warning I provided in the last sentence.